# Escritura en un diccionario de diccionarios de Python

Tags: python, diccionarios

tengo el siguiente diccionario:

```
Diccionario={'Boston Celtics': {'jugadores': ('Guerschon Yabusele'), 'partidos': {'Philadelphia 76ers': {'Tue Oct 16 2018': ('105', '87', '18624')}}}}
```

necesito crear un nuevo partido e intento hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
Diccionario["Boston Celtics"]["partidos"]["Chicago Bulls"]["Wed Nov 23 2018"]=("92","44","13221")
```

segun lo que he leido, cuando coloco una clave que no existe, esta se crea en el diccionario, pero al ejecutar me sale Keyerror:"Chicago Bulls"

cual seria la sintaxis adecuada para poder agregar dicho partido a mi diccionario y que quede de la siguiente manera??? gracias:

```
Diccionario={'Boston Celtics': {'jugadores': ('Guerschon Yabusele'), 'partidos': {'Philadelphia 76ers': {'Tue Oct 16 2018': ('105', '87', '18624'),"Chicago Bulls": {"Wed Nov 23 2018": ("92","44","13221")}}}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando en un diccionario accedes a una clave inexistente *para escribir*, efectivamente crea la clave, como en:

```
d = {}
d["nueva"] = 3
```

Estamos accediendo a `d["nueva"]` **para escribir** porque justo después aparece el signo `=` de asignación.

Sin embargo, cuando accedes a una clave inexistente *para leer*, no se crea la clave, sino que genera una excepción. Por ejemplo:

```
d = {}
print(d["nueva"])
```

En este caso el acceso es para lectura, y genera la excepción `KeyError`.

Esto es lo que te está ocurriendo, ya que tú en esencia tienes esto:

```
d = {}
d["nueva"]["otra"] = 3
```

Aquí estamos accediendo a dos clave, ninguna de las cuales existe. La asignación podría descomponerse en la siguiente secuencia de instrucciones, que para python es equivalente (de hecho algo así es lo que él ejecuta):

```
d = {}
aux = d["nueva"]
aux["otra"] = 3
```

Aquí se ve más claramente que, aunque el acceso a la clave `"otra"` es para escritura (y por tanto debería generarla), *antes* habría tenido que hacer un acceso a la clave `"nueva"` **para lectura**, y ahí es donde te genera el error.

En definitiva, para acceder a claves anidadas tienes que crear antes la clave "padre". Así:

```
d = {}
d["nueva"] = {}  # Es otro diccionario
d["nueva"]["otra"] = 3
```

En tu caso:

```
Diccionario={'Boston Celtics': {'jugadores': ('Guerschon Yabusele'), 'partidos': {'Philadelphia 76ers': {'Tue Oct 16 2018': ('105', '87', '18624')}}}}

Diccionario["Boston Celtics"]["partidos"]["Chicago Bulls"] = {}
Diccionario["Boston Celtics"]["partidos"]["Chicago Bulls"]["Wed Nov 23 2018"]=("92","44","13221")
```